# How to pattern match this efficiently?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I would like to match an integer array against the following pseudo patterns:
where `a` means these numbers are the equal or 0 (i.e. assume any number "equals" 0)

```
[| a; a; a; a; a; |]          // matches [| 1; 1; 0; 0; 1 |]
[| a; a; a; not a; a; |]      // matches [| 3; 3; 0; 2; 3 |]
[| a; a; not a; a; a; |]      // matches [| 4; 4; 2; 0; 4 |]
[| a; not a; a; a; not a; |]  // matches [| 1; 2; 0; 0; 3 |]
[| a; a; a; not a; a; |]      // matches [| 1; 1; 0; 4; 1 |]
[| not a; a; a; a; a; |]      // matches [| 5; 1; 0; 1; 1 |]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I don't really get what `a` and what `not a` means here. Can you make that more clear? Does `a` mean "0 or 1" and `not a` mean "any other number"?

Comment: Ultimatemly chained if statements are probably fastest.  Is there any real realson not to switch away from match statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is just a computational task, so it can't look *very* beautiful. Nevertheless, here's my try. Note I used a `string` for "a" versus "not a" for better readability.

```
// Define possible return values
type TriState<'T> = | Yes of 'T | No of 'T | Unknown with 
    override this.ToString() =
        match this with
        | Unknown   -> "Unknown"
        | Yes value -> sprintf "Array matches, common value %A" value
        | No value  -> sprintf "Array mismatches, common value %A" value

// a boilerplate function
let matchA (pat: string) xs =
    let mustBeA, mustNotBeA =
        List.zip
            (xs |> Array.toList)
            (pat.ToCharArray() |> Array.toList)
        |> List.partition (snd >> ( (=) 'A'))
    // these values must be all equal
    let mustBeA' =
        mustBeA |> List.map fst |> List.filter ( (<>) 0)
    // these values must NOT be equal to the value taken from above
    let mustNotBeA' =
        mustNotBeA |> List.map fst
    match mustBeA' with
    | []            -> Unknown   // can't find the "must" value
                                 // due all "must" values are zero
    | mustValue::_  ->           // we have bootstrap value to compare against
        if (List.forall ( (=) mustValue) mustBeA')
            && (List.forall ( (<>) mustValue) mustNotBeA')
        then Yes mustValue
        else No mustValue
```

Now, testing:

```
[| 1; 2; 0; 0; 3 |] |> matchA "ABAAB" |> printf "%A\n" // Yes 1
[| 4; 4; 2; 0; 4 |] |> matchA "AABAA" |> printf "%A\n" // Yes 4
[| 5; 1; 0; 1; 1 |] |> matchA "BAAAA" |> printf "%A\n" // Yes 1
```

Of course, you can wrap it into a parameterized Active Pattern:

```
let (|MatchesA|_|) pattern arr =
    matchA pattern arr |> function | Yes x -> Some x | _ -> None

match [| 1; 2; 0; 0; 3 |] with
| MatchesA ("AAAAB") x -> sprintf "Pattern1 %d" x
| MatchesA ("ABAAB") x -> sprintf "Pattern2 %d" x
| _                    -> "Unknown"
|> printf "%A\n"
```

Answer (score 5):

In your examples, the first element of the array is always `a` you can match on a boolean array:

```
match Array.map (fun x -> x = Array.get arr 0 || x = 0) arr with
| [| true; true; true; true; true; |] -> ... // matches [| 1; 1; 0; 0; 1 |]
| [| true; true; true; false; true; |] -> ... // matches [| 3; 3; 0; 2; 3 |]
| [| true; true; false; true; true; |] -> ... // matches [| 4; 4; 2; 0; 4 |]
| [| true; false; true; true; false; |] -> ... // matches [| 1; 2; 0; 0; 3 |]
| [| true; true; true; false; true; |] -> ... // matches [| 1; 1; 0; 4; 1 |]
| _ -> ...
```

This will create a temporary array, but it isn't a big deal with arrays of small sizes.

**UPDATE:**

If the first `a` is in another column, you simply project on that column and do another pattern matching (there are at most 5 matches for 5 columns).

```
match Array.map (fun x -> x = Array.get arr 1 || x = 0) arr with
| [| false; true; true; true; true; |] -> ... // matches [| 5; 1; 0; 1; 1 |]
| ...
```

That said, when the number and the complexity of pseudo-patterns grow, it's better to use functions instead of pattern matching.

Comment: You could group pseudo-patterns by columns and do several `match`. But it seems you expect too much from pattern matching. When pseudo-patterns are too complex, it's time to create functions to recognize them.

Comment: when i had another look, i figured out it was wrong (actually my example was wrong). As [| true; true; true; true; true; |] -> ... // matches [| 0; 1; 2; 3; 4 |] in your method

Answer (score 2):

You can define an active pattern that is parameterized by a *pattern* that you want to detect. In your example, you write these *patterns* using a pseudo-syntax with array containing either `a` or `not a`, but you could quite easily write them as actual arrays that contain the same value when you want to have matching values in the input. For example, something like:

```
[| 'a'; 'a'; 'b'; 'a'; 'a'; |]
```

It could even be a string as in @bytebuster's solution (you can convert `string` to `char[]` using the `ToCharArray` method). Then you can define active pattern:

```
let inline (|ArrayPattern|_|) pattern input =
  let matches =
    Array.zip pattern input
    |> Seq.groupBy fst 
    |> Seq.forall (fun (_, values) -> 
        let cases = values |> Seq.map snd |> set
        Set.count (cases - Set.singleton 0) <= 1)
  if matches then Some() else None
```

I guess this is essentially the same as what @bytebuster implements. Here, I group the elements of the input array by their corresponding key in the pattern and then use set operations to check that there is at most one non-zero value for each group.

To use it, you can now match an `int[]` against `ArrayPattern [| ... |]` where the array parameter specifies the specific pattern you're looking for:

```
match [| 1; 1; 2; 0; 1 |] with 
| ArrayPattern [| 'a'; 'a'; 'b'; 'a'; 'a'; |] -> printfn "match"
| _ -> printfn "not"
```